# How to setState in a onTick event that ticks every millisecond

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cesiumjs

I'm trying to set a state in an onTick event for a clock.

```
 <Viewer>
   <Clock
        startTime={start.clone()}
        stopTime={stop.clone()}
        currentTime={start.clone()}
        multiplier={50}
        onTick={_.throttle(handleValue, 1000)} // this thing ticks every millisecond
      />
    <Entity
          ref={ref} // here is the ref to get the value I want to set state with
          position={positionProperty}
          tracked
          selected
          model={{ uri: model, minimumPixelSize: 100, maximumScale: 100.0 }}
          availability={
            new TimeIntervalCollection([
              new TimeInterval({ start: start, stop: stop }),
            ])
          }
        />
 </Viewer>
```

Here is the handleValue function.

```
  const handleValue = (clock) => {
//setting the state here ( I want to display the chaning the value over time) 
  setHeadingValue(ref.current.cesiumElement._properties._heading.getValue(clock.currentTime));
    }
  };
```

The problem is it looks like it tries to re-render over and over which freezes the app.
Due to the nature of setState, this behavior makes sense. But I feel like there is an answer that's escaping me.
May I have some insight as to what I could do? I'm out of ideas.
I'm using Resium ( a react library) and right now I'm setting the value using `.getElementByID()` and appending to the dom.. which defeats using react in the first place...

Here is a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/resium-cesium-context-forked-bpjuw?file=/src/ViewerComponent.js

Some elements are not showing because we need a token, but that does not affect the functionality I'm looking for. Just open the console of the code sandbox and go to the ViewerComponent.js

thank you for your help

Comment: what behaviour are you trying to achieve? I mean you want to set value and not re-render component? But how do you want to use that value?

Comment: Are you saying that this `Clock` component implements *some* interval with a 1ms delay, and this is too many updates so you are trying to throttle this callback? Most browsers enforce a 4ms minimum interval/timer delay, and React tries to run a UI at 60 frames/second, which is about 17ms per render cycle, so trying to do anything faster than this is basically waste. If you are running a clock component why not just use an interval delay that matches the smallest interval you care about, which seems to be the 1 second throttling?

Comment: Thank you @DrewReese! The Cesium library for react is called Resium. They are the ones who provide the clock component: https://resium.darwineducation.com/components/Clock

I need to use the onTick event from that Clock to get the value as time goes by. Im trying to display a property in the UI that changes as time passes, like a car that is driving and the current speed. I want to save that speed in state but if I set state in the onTick event, the whole Cesium component tries to re-render. I have tried throttle and the Cesium map still freezes :(

Comment: Woah, that's a pretty cool library. Thank you for the extra details. There was a quite a bit to digest from the docs. Think you could create and provide us a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we could live debug?

Comment: Who is rendering <Clock /> ? Need an overview of who's rendering who aka component hierarchy.

Comment: @BadalSaibo The Viewer Components is rendering the <Clock /> I edited the question to show more

Comment: @DrewReese Here is my code sandbox, some elements dont load because I need to put a token there, but the main functionality is there. Open the console and see the tick event of the clock. https://codesandbox.io/s/resium-cesium-context-forked-bpjuw?file=/src/ViewerComponent.js

Comment: I see. What heading value are you trying to change with `setHeadingValue`? I'm also a bit confused by `ref.current.cesiumElement._properties._heading.getValue(clock.currentTime)`, does the `getValue` function take a parameter? What are you trying to do with the state update? I implemented callback throttling and that seems to work as expected so now I think your issue is more to do with the state update and what it may be triggering. Understanding what you are trying to do may help us see alternatives.

Comment: @DrewReese think of setHeadingValue as just a setValue from the set state. The ref.current.blah  all that is the value I want to set,  thats it. :) Im just trying to do setValue(value) but with the above variables.

Comment: Sure.... but if you are trying to accomplish similar behavior ***without*** using a state update, then it would be great to understand what the end goal is to be.

Comment: I can do what I need to do by selecting a div by ID and just  use `.textcontent` to append the text to that div, but that is not the react way of doing things. And state would allow me to make the information available to all my components even outside of cesium. 

The resium library allows me to use refs to access properties of particular Entities. Which is what `ref.current.cesiumElement._properties._heading.getValue(clock.currentTime)`is. I just want to get that property value on state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I see, the problem here not in the library, but in a way of managing calculation and visualization.

As few people already mentioned, for UI, user don't need more than 60fps, but for process sometimes we need more.

So the solution is to separate processing from visualization.

To be more generic, here is an example in pure JavaScript:

```js
// Here it may be some component 
const clockView = document.getElementById('speedyClock')

let state = null
// This function mimicking dispatch on state update 
function setState(val) {
  state = val
  clockView.innerHTML = state
} 

const FPS = 30


// Any state out of visualization scope
// Not the React state!!!
let history = []

let nextUiUpdate = Date.now()+(1000/FPS) 

/// Super speedy process
setInterval(function() {
  history.push(Math.random())
  const now = Date.now()
  
  // Update according to visual frame rate
  if(now >= nextUiUpdate) {
    // Prepare visual updates
    setState(JSON.stringify({count: history.length, history}, null, 2))
    history = []    
    nextUiUpdate = Date.now()+(1000/FPS)
  }
}, 1)
```

```html
<pre id="speedyClock"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you Oleg for your answer! Would you mind using my codesandbox and leaving some comments or an example with the particular case that I have with cesium? I think I get the general idea but an example on my codesandbox would really really be helpful :)

Comment: Just copy the functionality from my `setInterval` into yours `handleValue`. You may collect multiple values into some global variable (not react state). And if time to refresh, just `setState` with the latest or summary of collected values.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out and see if this fixes my problem! :D

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `requestAnimationFrame`, instead of `setInterval` as their is no point rerendering the React tree more than once every screen refresh.

Answer (score 2):

By using a combination of `shouldComponentUpdate` and `setState` you can effectively `setState` and prevent unnecessary renders.

[This is my codesandbox url to show it.](https://codesandbox.io/s/resium-cesium-context-forked-yysmb?file=/src/ViewerComponent.js)

You can access your wanted value as often as you want, but we need to prevent 1 render per millisecond with `shouldComponentUpdate` function.